# CRM 2011 using pre-image in plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm looking at using a pre-image for one of my plugins so i can get values in fields that haven't been changed. I've registered a pre-image for the entity in the plugin registration tool but when I've put some code in that tries to check it it doesn't find the image. So i was wondering what it was that I've missed that is stopping it from working. I've searched Google but couldn't really find anything, cant anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Post your code please :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you ensured your string key in your code matches the image you have registerd for your plugin step?

For example. 
Your code:    `Entity entity = (Entity)context.PreEntityImages["Target"];`
Then your Entity Alias and Name when registering the image should also be named to Target.

Comment: Yeah it was me being a bit silly there and mis-spelling the key in my code! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Jimmy, assume you are not triggering the plugin during a create operation as the pre images are not available during create.

This is another possibility that the one mentioned by peter and robben above.